# Im Making A Batch File Create Another File But i Cant add a parentheses

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a batch file make another batch file with parentheses like this

```
set brackleft ="("
set brackright =")"
@(
echo @echo off
echo if exist exp.txt %brackleft%
echo    goto a
echo %brackright% else %brackleft%
echo echo Bye
echo pause
echo %brackleft%
echo pause
echo :a
echo echo Hi
echo pause
) > Test.bat
```

But when I right click and edit the new batch file this comes up

```
@echo off
if exist exp.txt 
goto a
 else 
echo Bye
pause
ECHO is off.
pause
:a
echo Hi
pause
```

Comment: Use the escape character - `^`. So `(` becomes `^(`. Brackets have meaning, either specifying a group of commands or specifying the order of evaluation.

Comment: @Noodles That's not whole problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

```
rem          ↓ this space is harmful creates %brackleft % variable instead of %brackleft%
set brackleft ="("
set brackright =")"
rem           ↑ this space is harmful as well: creates %brackright % variable
rem                                                               ↑
```

Let's remove that harmful spaces:

```
set brackleft="("
set brackright=")"
```

Then, `echo %brackright% else %brackleft%` would result to `")" else "("`.

You need next syntax with [escaped both left and right parentheses](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) as `^(` and `^)`; Moreover, `^` caret should be escaped as well (see position of double quotes):

```
set "brackleft=^("
set "brackright=^)"
```

Comment: You can also use `set brackleft=^^(` and `set brackright=^^)`

Comment: You missed another error in his code. `echo %brackleft%` should be `echo %brackright%`, otherwise the parentheses don't match up.

Answer (score -1):

#### I can't add a parentheses

```
set brackleft ="("
set brackright =")"
```

You have created a variable with the name "brackleft " and "brackright " (note the trailing spaces).

> Any extra spaces around either the variable name or the string, will not be ignored, SET is not forgiving of extra spaces like many other scripting languages.

Source [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Notes:

- Remove the spaces before the `=`.
- You also need to remove the `"`s (otherwise they will be `echo`ed)
- You also need to escape the `(` and `)` in order for the `echo` to work later.
- `^^` is used to make a single `^` escape character.
- You should use `^^^` to escape the `(` or `)` inside an existing code block.
- Your logic seems to have a mistake. `echo %brackleft%` should probably be `echo %brackright%`, otherwise your parentheses don't match up.

So the code becomes:

```
set brackleft=^^^(
set brackright=^^^)
```

Corrected batch file:

```
set brackleft=^^^(
set brackright=^^^)
@(
echo @echo off
echo if exist exp.txt %brackleft%
echo    goto a
echo %brackright% else %brackleft%
echo echo Bye
echo pause
echo %brackright%
echo pause
echo :a
echo echo Hi
echo pause
) > Test.bat
```

Output:

```
F:\test>type Test.bat
@echo off
if exist exp.txt (
   goto a
) else (
echo Bye
pause
)
pause
:a
echo Hi
pause
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.

Comment: Actually you should use `set brackleft=^^^(` and `set brackright=^^^)`; thy the command lines within a parenthesised block using two carets only, then you will see that the closing `)` ends the block unintentionally...

Comment: As long as these lines are not inside of a parenthesised block, two `^^` are sufficient; however, as soon as you place them inside of a block, you will run into trouble; note that `^^)` constitutes a literal `^` and an *unescaped* `)`, which ends/closes a parenthesis-block...